# Truncate the same table in multiple databases using root account in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

When I need to truncate a table in the database I do this:

`TRUNCATE TABLE forums;`

But I have this table in hundreds of databases.

How to do it in all databases at once? Or better, in the selected ones.

For example something like:

`TRUNCATE IN MYDB1, MYDB2, MYDB3 TABLE forums;`

Any idea how to do something like that?

Comment: Write a stored procedure that gets all the database names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, and then prepares and executes a `TRUNCATE` statement for each of them.

Comment: hmm, I already have some of them that doesn't need to be truncated, because they contain vaalid data, so, I would like to select dbs taht I want to use truncate

Comment: You could create a table that lists all the databases you want to truncate in, and then loop over that instead of all the databases in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Unfortunately, SQL doesn't have arrays, so tables are the best way to represent lists like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the wonderful [commmon_schema](https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/) do do this task. Have a look into [`foreach`](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/query_script_flow_control.html). Something like this maybe:

```
foreach($table, $schema, $engine: table like 'forums%')
  if ($engine = 'innodb')
    TRUNCATE TABLE :$schema.:$table;
```